# jQuery every other background grey

Tags: jquery, html, css

Ok so i have this HTML and i am trying to style it so that every other line of the cart goes from white to grey. I know this is probably easier with CSS3 but since this needs support back to IE7 i think jQuery might be the better route.

```
        <div id="checkoutTable">
        <div id="checkoutRow" class="bold headline">
            <div id="checkoutCell" class="headline">Item <br>Number</div>
            <div id="checkoutCell" class="headline itemName">Item <br>Name</div>
            <div id="checkoutCell" class="headline">Quantity <br>Per Unit</div>
            <div id="checkoutCell" class="headline">Units Free <br>Remaining</div>
            <div id="checkoutCell" class="headline">Units <br>Ordered</div>
            <div id="checkoutCell" class="headline">Cost Per Unit <br>(USD)</div>
            <div id="checkoutCell" class="headline">Total Cost <br>(USD)</div>
        </div>
        <div id="checkoutRow" class="center cartCheckout">
            <div id="checkoutCell" class="first">FLT199</div>
            <div id="checkoutCell" class="first itemName">Vehicle Flyer</div>
            <div id="checkoutCell" class="first">1</div>
            <div id="checkoutCell" class="first">20</div>
            <div id="checkoutCell" class="first"><input name="unitsOrdered" id="" size="5"></div>
            <div id="checkoutCell" class="first">$10.00</div>
            <div id="checkoutCell" class="first">$0.00</div>
        </div>
        <div id="checkoutRow" class="center cartCheckout">
            <div id="checkoutCell" class="first">FLT199</div>
            <div id="checkoutCell" class="first itemName">Vehicle Flyer</div>
            <div id="checkoutCell" class="first">1</div>
            <div id="checkoutCell" class="first">20</div>
            <div id="checkoutCell" class="first"><input name="unitsOrdered" id="" size="5"></div>
            <div id="checkoutCell" class="first">$10.00</div>
            <div id="checkoutCell" class="first">$0.00</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Then i thought that this jQuery would do the trick but it isn't working.

```
  $(function() {
    $(".cartCheckout:even").css("background", "#ccc;");
  });
```

Comment: The even cartCheckout row isnt changing the BG color

Comment: `#ccc;` isn't a valid color. Also, you could try `backgroundColor` instead of `background`.

Comment: check this line: $(".cartCheckout:even").css("background", "#ccc;");
i think you have a typpo here. #ccc (no ; here)

Comment: Your markup implies that you're styling this to look like a table so why not actually use a table? Also, IDs should be used once and only once on a page, having a ton of #checkoutCell is bad practice.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an extra `;` in the color `#ccc;` which is not valid. If you change it to `#ccc` it will work as shown in the demo.

```
$(function() {
    $(".cartCheckout:even").css("background", "#ccc");
  });
```

See [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/adLvm/2/)

Comment: Now i don't understand why it isnt working on my code but it is in your demo UGGHHH

Comment: @Travis i added explanation to the answer

Comment: Yeah i see that but for some reason it isn't working locally on my computer... I thought that i was close let me see if i can get it up and online and maybe you can take a look there...

Comment: you have to use `$(".center:even").css("backgroundColor", "#ccc")` on that page because you are using a different class and if you see you have the `div` covered with child `div`. it is getting the color, but you can't see it.

Comment: try `$(".center:even").children().css("backgroundColor", "#ccc")` but be careful I'musing all `children()`, you can use that method to pick what you want using selectors.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".cartCheckout:even").css("background", "#ccc");
});
```

here is a working code - http://jsfiddle.net/maximua/6fwX4/